How to initialize FFmpeg in .NET MAUI-Windows
I have installed the bin using winget install "FFmpeg (Shared)" on Windows 11 22631.3810. it installs successfully but when running FFmpegInit.Initialise() I get System.NotSupportedException: 'Specified method is not supported.' I have also tried setting the logLevel to FfmpegLogLevelEnum.AV_LOG_FATAL , and I got the same exception. I tried to set the libPath to C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WinGet\Packages\Gyan.FFmpeg.Shared_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe\ffmpeg-7.0.1-full_build-shared\bin and I got the same exeption
